# Getting force close when wanting to change focus from one EditText to Another

Tags: java, android, focus, android-edittext

This is for my Android App. I have two EditText fields set to a maximum of one character that can be input in each field.  Once the user inputs the first character I would like the focus to automatically jump to the second EditText field.  I set up an addTextChangedListener on the first Edit Text and had it listen for when the text string is > 1.  Then I call request focus on the second Edit Text.  However, I keep receiving a force close when I input the character in the first Edit Text box.  From what I've looked on StackOverflow, this should work.  Anyone have any idea why it is not? I posted the relevant code below.  Thanks.

```
    LinearLayout llview = new LinearLayout(this);
    llview.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    EditText character1 = new EditText(this);
    EditText character2 = new EditText(this);
    character2.setId(2);

    character1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

        EditText character2 = (EditText) findViewById(2);

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            if(s.length()>0)
            {
                character2.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after){}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,int count) {}

    }); 
           llview.addView(character1);
           llview.addView(character2);
           this.setContentView(llview);
```

Comment: What does the stacktrace say?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you've posted all of the relevant code. It would seem that you are building your view hierarchy programmatically (rather than using a layout file), yet there is no code showing where you insert character1 and character2 into the view hierarchy. It would be helpful if you posted the code for building your view hierarchy.

Also, what debugging steps have you attempted so far? Have you set breakpoints to confirm that your variables are not null pointers when you invoke methods on them? Have you done a stack trace?

If I was to guess just based on this code segment you posted, then I would have to guess that you haven't inserted character1 and character2 into your activity's view hierarchy and findViewById(2) is simply returning null. Have you checked to see that findViewById(2) is in fact returning something other than null?

Comment: I added the relevant info.  I've cut out some of the irrelevant code.  Basically, if the code character2.requestFocus(); is not present , everything works fine. ( both edittexts show in the view and I can edit them.  However, with the code character2.requestFocus(); , as soon as I enter a character in character1 edittext, I get a force close.

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint on the line containing character2.requestFocus() to see if character2 is in fact pointing to null?

Comment: if you removed `character2.setId(2);` does it help? am just wondering if number 2 is reserved to the system.

Comment: I tried changing the ID to a larger number and same problem.  I ended up just using 1 textedit instead of 4.  Was trying to make a password input box with 4 single digit numberical inputs and have the focus jump to next box once a digit was entered.  I've seen some apps do this, but decided 1 box with a 4 digit input would work as well.  Thanks